# xrandr --dpi doesn't work

Tags: 16.10, xrandr

I recently made the switch from Debian Jessie to Ubuntu 16.10 (mostly because I bought a new laptop and needed a little more recent kernel for that). I'm using i3 and had a little script that if I had the 4k screen connected, enabled output on the 4k screen and set the dpi higher, basically a `xrandr --output ... --dpi 144`.

This used to work quite well for me; 90% of the applications and all GTK and Qt applications respected this dpi setting.

Now, on Ubuntu doing a `xrandr --dpi 144` does not not have much effect. Besides i3 no other application seems to respect it...

what am I missing? It used to work well on Jessie.